# Passing variables to PHP via HttpURLConnection

Tags: php, android, httpurlconnection

I am using a **HTTPURLConnection** to upload a sound file from my application to my server by uploading to a **php** file. In my php file I save the uploaded audio into a directory called uploads. However, I want to pass my php file a variable(username:usernameval) from my application along with the HTTPURLConnection in which is the name of the directory I want the sound file to be uploaded. I am just confused as to how to pass it the variable from my front end.

**Android upload code**

```
public void uploadFile() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            DataInputStream inStream = null;
            String existingFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myaudio.3gp";
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            String urlString = "urlgoeshere";
            try {
                //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(existingFileName));
                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                // Allow Outputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                // Don't use a cached copy.
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                // Use a post method.
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + existingFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                // close streams
                Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
            }
            //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
            try {
                inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                String str;
                while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
                }
                inStream.close();

            } catch (IOException ioex) {
                Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

**php file**

```
<?php
// Where the file is going to be placedc
echo "in php";
$username = $_POST['username'];
$target_path = "uploads/";
if (file_exists('uploads/')) {
//    mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
  echo "username is = " + $username;
}

/* Add the original filename to our target path.
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " .$target_path;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> public void setRequestProperty (String field, String newValue) Added
>   in API level 1 Sets the value of the specified request header field.
>   The value will only be used by the current URLConnection instance.
>   This method can only be called before the connection is established.

By looking at your php file, I assume that you get the user name from post headers.

So in order to get the user name value you need to set it in your request headers:

```
...
con.setRequestProperty("username","your_user_name");
...
```

before the connection is established.

Comment: Hey friend. I recieved <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: username in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\upload.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br /> from the php file

Comment: stackoverflow.com/a/4261200/6153485 you need to initialize the variable